# How to change visibility of static Textview variable from another fragment?

Tags: android, textview, visibility

I have two fragments A and B. In my 'A' fragment, there is Textview variable and which is public static. I want to access fragment 'A' Textview variable and change its visibility in fragment 'B'. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?  Or anyone could tell me how to pass Textview from Fragment 'A' to Fragment 'B'.

Comment: if you have public static variable you can access it by ClassName.variable name

Comment: I used same as u mention above. @Arshad sir

Comment: Never create your view as static as it will not destroy and can cause memory leakage. I would suggest to use interface concept instead of static.

Comment: @PriyankaG Are you getting some error in doing so? As Danish said, you can also try using interface for the same

Comment: ok sir, but can u explain what is the content of an interface? @Danish Sharma sir

Comment: I'm not getting any type of an error. @ Arshad sir

Answer (score 0):

make textview object as public static like below ..

first fragment like make

```
  public static TextView textView;
```

onCreate() method..

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

then second fragment in oncreate method ..

```
FragmentName. textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access from fragment A to parent activity and tell the activity to call the one of the fragment B methods like setTextViewAText(String str)

for more information about communicating between fragment and activity see this link : 
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html